# How do I find out what is running immediately following login?

Tags: 13.04, login, performance

A few weeks ago, I must have installed an update or new package that now gives me ~10 seconds of black screen immediately following login, until my wallpaper and the Unity interface appears. Sometimes, but not always, it takes an extra ~3 seconds for the appindicators (including the shutdown/settings indicator) to appear.

From what I understand, bootchart only measures the boot process until the login screen is reached. Is there a similar utility that can track which processes run at login?

Answer (score 1):

You use the terminal and look up the processes manually. For that, type in the console:

```
  ps aux
```

The use of grep is very usefull in combination with that e.g.

```
ps aux | grep dbus
```